# Is editing a question to make it more generalized acceptable?

Tags: discussion, editing

So yesterday, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/291910/3062) was asked.

It assumes that the user themselves caused the change and the title reflects that. I answered it, explaining that it was a change for everyone that went in yesterday.

However, I watched [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/285081/3062) get flooded with non-answers demanding an explanation for an issue (this question was actually not related to what happened, as it was asked long before the change) and [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/291993/whats-wrong-with-my-pok%C3%A9mons-cp) was just asked, primarily in rant form.

Would it be acceptable to edit the first question to make it more generalized, so that people would be more likely to see it instead of asking another question? Or would this fail to preserve the original author's intent?

I also considered creating my own Q&A to solve the issue, but it would definitely be (rightly) considered a duplicate.

Comment: Honestly, I think the first question should be called a duplicate of the second with an answer adressing the new patch. The question is essentially the same but in a different time frame. The questions in Arqade (imo) should be intemporal. No matter when you read them you should have the answer to your question if the problem is the one explained in the question. Not an answer to the problem at hand and I'm not exactly sure how to solve this one.